# How to include <cuda_runtime.h> in .cpp file

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I have problem to include `<cuda_runtime.h>` in `.cpp` file. Error: `Cannot include file: cuda_runtime.h: No such file or directory`.

I am trying to complie code from Rob Farber ( http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/222600097?pgno=1 ).

I have compiled few cuda codes before but `<cuda_runtime.h>` was allways included in `.cu` file.

I am using VS 2008 Express.

Q: Do I have to link VS somehow different so it knows where to look for `<cuda_runtime.h>`?

Comment: This header is located in <path_to_instalation>\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\<version>\include\cuda_runtime.h. The reason is, maybe, that cl compiled includes does not propagated in nvcc includes.Try to pass it manually.

Comment: thx. Is there any way how to force VS to look in <path_to_instalation>\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\<version>\include directory when it is looking for .h files? I have to include many .h file so I am looking for some convenient way.

Comment: In you solution properties in `VC++ directories` add cuda toolkit include directories. You can specify library and runtime directories for cuda too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2008, add the path of the include files in Visual C++ directories.

"Installation Path"\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\"version"\include\

### Here is the procedure:

In Visual Studio 2008, go to
 - Tools -> Options -> Projects And Solutions -> Visual C++ Directories.
 - Select **include files** from the drop down list named "Show Directories For".
 - Add new item by clicking the yellow button below the drop down list.
 - Paste the include fles path here.
 - Verify the correctness of path by clicking the check button on left of yellow button
 - Click ok and restart visual studio.

Now Visual Studio 2008 will know where the include file is located.

Comment: This method is obsolete by newer VS editions.   Now, the place you add such things in in the project properties.   Open VS. Right-click on the project -> properties.   In the new pop up, Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories.   Then add your new path in the Include Directories area.   Now, for CUDA, it links into VS on install.   So, you actually do something slightly different.   Open VS, select the project, then select Project from the menu -> Build Customizations, then in the new dialog, put a check box next to CUDA.   You may have to add cudart.lib to your additional dependencies.

Comment: @LawfulEvil... Thanks to NVIDIA, the CUDA template included with NSIGHT saves us all the headache.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of setting up a hard-coded path - which you will most likely have when locating CUDA installation on your machine - you can also add `cudart.lib` as additional dependency for the linker.

Right click on the project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies. Add `cudart.lib` there.

Comment: This helps me: Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies add cudart_static.lib, and set actual path to libs dir in Project > Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Dependencies